Why doesn't Selenium start?
I'm trying to start Selenium (4.13.0) on an Ubuntu (20.04) server as a Docker container. The hard drive is formatted with xfs and quota is enabled. The container stops immediately with an error.
The same command runs fine with an ext4 formatted hard drive with no  quota. However, other containers (Spring Boot and Python) run fine with xfs and quota.
Background
I'm trying to limit storage space (writeable layer) for Docker containers, so I followed Set storage driver options per container (--storage-opt).
Command
docker container run 
  --log-driver local 
  --detach 
  --shm-size=1g 
  --name selenium 
  --env SE_NODE_OVERRIDE_MAX_SESSIONS=true 
  --env SE_NODE_MAX_SESSIONS=10 
  --env SE_NODE_SESSION_TIMEOUT=180 
  selenium/standalone-chrome:4.13.0      

Logs
2024-04-26 10:50:46.138 Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-04-26 10:50:46.138   File "/usr/bin/supervisord", line 11, in <module>
2024-04-26 10:50:46.138     load_entry_point('supervisor==4.1.0', 'console_scripts', 'supervisord')()
2024-04-26 10:50:46.138   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/supervisor/supervisord.py", line 350, in main
2024-04-26 10:50:46.138     options = ServerOptions()
2024-04-26 10:50:46.138   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/supervisor/options.py", line 439, in __init__
2024-04-26 10:50:46.138     existing_directory, default=tempfile.gettempdir())
2024-04-26 10:50:46.138   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tempfile.py", line 425, in gettempdir
2024-04-26 10:50:46.138     tempdir = _get_default_tempdir()
2024-04-26 10:50:46.138   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tempfile.py", line 357, in _get_default_tempdir
2024-04-26 10:50:46.138     raise FileNotFoundError(_errno.ENOENT,
2024-04-26 10:50:46.138 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No usable temporary directory found in ['/tmp', '/var/tmp', '/usr/tmp', '/']

Configuration on the host
ubuntu@my-server:~$ cat /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
    "data-root": "/mnt/docker-data"
}

ubuntu@my-server:~$ cat /etc/fstab
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs                           /                       ext4    defaults,discard                        0 0
UUID=f37b6675-93d5-405d-a68e-aeb459872297       /mnt/docker-data        xfs     defaults,quota,prjquota,pquota,gquota   0 0

Research

I read No usable temporary directory found and checked disk usage on the host system:
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       9.7G  6.1G  3.6G  63% /
/dev/xvdc        22G   14G  8.5G  62% /mnt/docker-data

and in the Docker Container:
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay          22G   14G  8.5G  62% /


I have disabled the quota but I get the same error message.

I read Use the OverlayFS storage driver and checked xfs_info:
root@my-server:/home/ubuntu# xfs_info /dev/xvdc
meta-data=/dev/xvdc              isize=512    agcount=4, agsize=1441792 blks
         =                       sectsz=512   attr=2, projid32bit=1
         =                       crc=1        finobt=1, sparse=1, rmapbt=0
         =                       reflink=1
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=5767168, imaxpct=25
         =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0, ftype=1
log      =internal log           bsize=4096   blocks=2816, version=2
         =                       sectsz=512   sunit=0 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0


I read Use the OverlayFS storage driver and checked docker info:
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
 userxattr: false


I read No usable temporary directory found and checked the inodes on the host:
Filesystem       Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/xvdc      11534336 202409 11331927    2% /mnt/docker-data

and in the Docker Container:
Filesystem       Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
overlay        11534336 202524 11331812    2% /


I read No usable temporary directory found and checked the read-only flag on the host:
/dev/xvdc on /mnt/docker-data type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,usrquota,prjquota,grpquota)


I read tempfile.py and checked permissions of /tmp in the container:
drwxr-xr-t   1 root root  23 Apr 29 07:46 tmp

So something changed the permissions. In the original image, the permissons are drwxrwxrwt.


I cannot use the default entry point becaus of the error, so I startet the container with entry point bash to check the values. I don't know, if this changes the values.
Question
How to start Selenium in a Docker container on a xfs disk with quota enabled?

@JeffC What do you think is not minimal? What can I remove? I see only the env variables, which are not minimal.

To reproduce it, you have to format the disk with xsf, change the daemon.json, add the mount point to fstab and run the command line.

Quoting from the docstring of the call that fails: We determine whether or not a candidate temp dir is usable by trying to create and write to a file in that directory.  If this is successful, the test file is deleted.  To prevent denial of service, the name of the test file must be randomized. -- those docs generally mean what they say; thus, the appropriate next step is to inspect the actual permissions of /tmp within the container.

Don't just look at the permissions in the container -- actually try to create a file and see if it works. Permissions aren't everything -- there are discretionary access control layers, f/e, that can prevent actions where the permissions say they should be allowed.

If docker were using tmpfs (as I'd argue it should), xfs quota wouldn't matter at all (at least, not for purposes of being able to successfully write to /tmp). Per https://docs.docker.com/storage/tmpfs/, creation of tmpfs mounts within a Docker namespace is supported.

@CharlesDuffy Basically you are right, but Selenium writes files at different locations. It is not only one directory. It is not easy to find all these locations. However, I could at least mount the /tmp dir. But then I need a bigger machine with more memory, because tmpfs is only in memory.

"I have disabled the quota but I get the same error message...."    maybe restart from a clean copy of selenium/standalone-chrome, which should run without errors? and then try to add quota ?

@Luuk Thank you, your comment helped me. After removing container and image and pull a clean image, it worked. However, I don't know, why the container changed the permissions of the dir. I didn't do that and I see no script in the container, which does it.

@CharlesDuffy Thank you for your help. Friday, I thought I saw the right permissions, but  today I saw the wrong permissions. Removing the Docker container was not enough. I had also to remove the image. I can't explain it, because the image should be read only. All changes should be in the writeable layer.

Apparently the image was damaged somehow (if anyone knows, how an image can damaged in this way, please add a comment).
To fix the problem, I had to delete the image and pull a clean one. I did following:

Remove Docker containers
docker container prune


Remove Docker images
docker image prune -a


Start Docker container
docker container run 
  --log-driver local 
  --detach 
  --shm-size=1g 
  --name selenium 
  --env SE_NODE_OVERRIDE_MAX_SESSIONS=true 
  --env SE_NODE_MAX_SESSIONS=10 
  --env SE_NODE_SESSION_TIMEOUT=180 
  selenium/standalone-chrome:4.13.0   



After these steps, the dir had the right permissions:
drwxrwxrwt   1 root root  23 Oct  4  2023 tmp

